# Why does my graphics card glitch in this particular pattern?

Tags: memory, graphics, initialization, driver

When my computer suspends and resumes, the desktop background on Ubuntu becomes this interesting pattern.

[image]

I am *not* asking for help debugging or resolving this glitch, but I am interested in what process might be producing this particular pattern.

The non-glitch version of this desktop background is a noise pattern. It looks to me like the process is 1) fill with a flat colour, 2) add or xor some noise in the lower order bits, so I'm speculating that between steps 1 and 2 something is initializing the memory with this four-colour pattern to clobber the flat fill (or perhaps it happens instead).

Why would a graphics driver want to initialize memory with such a pattern?